# How to print the output of a bash terminal if it's being called from a batch script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, batch-file

I've written a batch script that opens a bash terminal and do the following:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set BASHPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\"
set START_DIR=%CD%

set release=%1
echo Release outside cyg: %release%
set PATH=%BASHPATH%;%PATH%

%BASHPATH%\bash -l -c "echo Release inside cyg: $release \ && echo Directory: $START_DIR \ && cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd .. \ && cd iv_system4 \ && cd ports \ && cd visualC12 \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua C:\sequences\FCW_APTINA\SECTION_1\$release\VASP_DUN722_20160307_Krk_Krk_113048_092_1.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_DUN722_20160307_Krk_Krk_113048_092_1_$release.xml \ && echo First XML generated \ && exit; bash";
%BASHPATH%\bash -l -c "echo Release inside cyg: $release \ && echo Directory: $START_DIR \ && cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd .. \ && cd iv_system4 \ && cd ports \ && cd visualC12 \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua C:\sequences\FCW_APTINA\SECTION_1\$release\VASP_DUN722_20160307_Krk_Krk_140604_050_1.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_DUN722_20160307_Krk_Krk_140604_050_1_$release.xml \ && echo Second XML generated \ && exit; bash";
%BASHPATH%\bash -l -c "echo Release inside cyg: $release \ && echo Directory: $START_DIR \ && cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd .. \ && cd iv_system4 \ && cd ports \ && cd visualC12 \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua C:\sequences\FCW_APTINA\SECTION_1\$release\VASP_DUN722_20160308_Krk_Bra_171516_012_1.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_DUN722_20160308_Krk_Bra_171516_012_1_$release.xml \ && echo Third XML generated \ && exit; bash";
%BASHPATH%\bash -l -c "echo Release inside cyg: $release \ && echo Directory: $START_DIR \ && cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd .. \ && cd iv_system4 \ && cd ports \ && cd visualC12 \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua C:\sequences\FCW_APTINA\SECTION_1\$release\VASP_DUN722_20160309_Krk_Bra_124926_117_1.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_DUN722_20160309_Krk_Bra_124926_117_1_$release.xml \ && echo Fourth XML generated \ && exit; bash";
%BASHPATH%\bash -l -c "echo Release inside cyg: $release \ && echo Directory: $START_DIR \ && cd $START_DIR \ && cd .. \ && cd .. \ && cd iv_system4 \ && cd ports \ && cd visualC12 \ && cd Debug \ && ./iv4_console.exe ../embedded/LUA/analysis/verbose-udp-toxml.lua C:\sequences\FCW_APTINA\SECTION_1\$release\VASP_DUN722_20160317_KRK_KRK_105146_011_1.dvl &>../../../../FCW/ObjectDetectionTest/VASP_DUN722_20160317_KRK_KRK_105146_011_1_$release.xml \ && echo Fifth XML generated \ && exit; bash";

set CYGWINPATH="C:\cygwin64\bin"
set PATH=%CYGWINPATH%;%PATH%

ENDLOCAL
```

For debugging purposes, I need to print the stdout of the bash terminal. How could I do this?

Comment: Now is that a terminal emulator or a bash shell you launch? It is either or, not both...

Comment: @arkascha Actually I don't know the difference!

Comment: A terminal emulator is a program represented by a window on a desktop you can use as if working with a classical terminal. In it some application can be executed, for example a shell. A shell on the other hand is "only" a command interpreter, it has to be executed inside something else, another shell or a console or a terminal.

Comment: Then I think this is a terminal emulator.

Comment: If so you have no access to the standard output of the bash interpreter, since that is claimed by the terminal. You will have to redirect the output into a log file or file system pipe to be able to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Opening a command prompt ( and running the script above should print everything in on the screen that any of those programs writes to stdout. If that doesn't happend, then there is something which you didn't tell us.

That said: Mixing BASH and BAT will get you in trouble. They have different opinions about many things and switching between the two will confuse you, especially when you're not an expert in both.

Since you use BASH to invoke an Windows executable, I suggest that you scratch BASH and use PowerShell. PowerShell is much more like BASH, but it understands Windows (i.e. paths with backslashes). Just like in BASH, PowerShell will allow to you to redirect the output of `iv4_console` to a file or pipe it back to the script for further processing.

All those things can be done with BAT, too, but the many "features" will drive you insane in the process.

Apart from that, there are several problems in your script. The `; bash"` at the end of several lines will start a new bash shell. That shell will stop the script and wait for you to type commands.

Avoid `cd x && cd y`, use `cd x/y` instead.